# Highly CPU power consuming process hides itself from process list

Tags: 16.04, cpu, process

recently my PC very often occurs to be very slow. It happens especially during video playing (e.g. netflix, but also local files), that the PC just stops doing anything, the mouse moves extremely slow, but often the situation relaxes after 1 or 2 minutes.

When I check the resources tab of system monitor I see a CPU usage of 100% on all of my 4 cores. But when I check the process list and try to kill the highest CPU user, I just don't find anything. It just shows some 10% usage (2 or 3 processes), but they don't sum up to 100% at all.

Does anybody know, what happens here? How can I find the problematic process? Could it be some malware, that hides from the process list? Or could it be some system feature?

Thanks for your help in advance :)

BTW: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with Unity

Comment: System Monitor might not show you everything unless you have "all processes" selected in it.  It default only shows you *your* processes.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just found 4 processes of the root user that are called kidle_inject/0 (and 1-3). I found the following page: https://askubuntu.com/questions/584636/kidle-inject-causing-very-high-load, tried the command in the top rated answer and now I'm waiting for the next occurence (hopefully it doesn't occur)

Comment: Related issue also being addressed today for another user: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1153613/ubuntu-19-kidle-inject-process?noredirect=1#comment1918797_1153613

Comment: Just disabling intel_powerclamp is the wrong thing to do. You should investigate and understand why your computer is overheating such that thermal throttling is kicking in and solve that issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks Doug Smythies. I also read that in the second answer of the question that I linked. I think I'll clean my fan soon and do some further checks