# Can't find what loads CPU

Tags: 14.10, cpu, system-monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 x64 on my Dell XPS 15 9530 laptop. I noticed that my CPU is loaded pretty heavily, although I can't find the process(es) which take(s) these resources.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xx3Xn.png]`

<sub>**Processes sorted by % CPU used**</sub>
[image]

Can someone please point out a place to look at?`

Comment: Have you tried `top` (from terminal) ?

Comment: try kill chrome it use too much memory, if you cannot live without chrome then upgrade your computer ;)

Comment: memory isn't a problem, CPU usage is. @MarkWilliams ok, so top shows that **kidle_inject** takes those resources. It looks like a [feature](http://askubuntu.com/questions/482307/kidle-inject-uses-cpu-power-without-apparent-reason).

Comment: it seems like you're only showing processes from your own user account, so you're omitting all the processes run by the system and not seeing the whole picture.
Try opening a terminal and look at the output of 'top', it will give you all processes of all users by default.

Comment: Or you can click on the View button in the system monitor and check View All Processes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that it's **Kidle_inject** process which takes my CPU resources.

Thanks all for pointing me the way to see this (command-line **Top** command, or changing view to "All Processes" in system-monitor).

You can read more about **Kidle_inject** process problem [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482307/kidle-inject-uses-cpu-power-without-apparent-reason?lq=1).

Answer (score 1):

If your machine is not one of the fastest, I would assume that the system-monitor CPU-graph window itself is eating the CPU time.
I have Intel Duo 2x2.0GHz and I can't get the displayed load below maybe 50% if that graph window is open.

Go to the settings and adjust the refresh delay to 1sec or so. That should make a huge difference, but at least for me, it does not save this setting.

Or check the CPU usage with other tools like `top` from the terminal or `indicator-multiload` (usually has to be installed first), which displays a small graph in your panel.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. I've figured out that it is kidle_inject that takes these resources.